# Riddle: Wrong fight to pick

Tags: riddle

Here's a short and sweet riddle.

> You might have heard not to mess with me.
>
> Hit me once and it's on.
>
> Hit me again and it's lights out for you!

Who or what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> a light switch?

If I hit you once

> I'll turn the lights on

If I hit you again

> I'll turn the lights off

Comment: i was trying to hide the answer like that. how can i do it?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling msm.oliveira! I have edited you answer to include spoiler tags ">!" so that your answer is hidden for people who do not wish to see possible solutions. For a multi-line spoil tag use ">! <br>" to add a new line

Comment: ok.Thanks. i was looking [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help) where i could hide the text